# Getting coefficient of each row in linear regression in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, extjs, scikit-learn, linear-regression

so I am reading from a CSV file and tried to use get the coefficient of every row

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path))
X = df['param_a']
y= df['param_b']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y)
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)


print('Coefficients: \n', reg.coef_)
```

this returns an error:

```
"Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray=[-100    0    0  100  -20  250  200 -125 -250    0   20 -250 -200  125  -10].\nReshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."
```

I'm trying to get the coefficient of every corresponding row to my grid.[image: please see grid image here]

anyone, please help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem relies upon the way you are defining both `X` and `y`.
you should try adding an extra pair of square bracers. 
thus changing this:

```
X = df['param_a']
y= df['param_b']
```

to this:

```
X = df[['param_a']]
y= df[['param_b']]
```

hope this helps

Comment: it still returns the same error to me:

"Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:\narray=[-125  100  -10  250 -200   10 -125    0  125    0  250 -100 -250  125  -20].\nReshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

Comment: @Forozo, it only returns one value [[ 0.00110844]]. Is it possible to get the coefficient of each of the rows? thanks

Comment: Coefficients don't really work that way. simply put, coefficients show you how important a column is in the calculation of your target vector y. 0.0011084 is an extremely low coefficient in your case. I would suggest you to add more features to your data or increase the size of your data.

Comment: im trying to do this http://bigdata-madesimple.com/how-to-run-linear-regression-in-python-scikit-learn/ where each row has a corresponding coefficient? Im also trying to do the code?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are referring to this photo from your [link](http://bigdata-madesimple.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/pd-data-frame.png) as you can see the first column is labelled features meaning that every label you see in the column refers to a feature from his dataframe (which is made of many rows, in your case `param_a` is your feature) then next to it he puts the coefficient of the feature. If he was to do the same table with your dataframe he would put `param_a` in the feature column and `0.00110844` in the estimatecoefficient column.